# SWRevealViewController not showing up after pushing to another storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a logIn storyboard tied up a SWRevealViewcontroller that has two landing points Storyboard1(sw_front) and Storyboard2 (sw_front). I can successfully go through to the Storyboard1 and Storyboard2 -  my problem is i cannot access my rearViewcontroller (menu icon) even thought i have set up the code. Here is the code to access the Storyboard:

```
if ([self.sitRUser isParent]) {
                                   //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:PARENT_HOME_SEGUE sender:self];
                                   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"HomeStoryboard" bundle:nil];
                                   HomeViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

                                   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
                                   [navController setViewControllers: @[rootViewController] animated: YES];

                                   UIStoryboard *storyboardLogin = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"LogIn" bundle:nil];

                                   MenuTableViewController *rearViewController = [storyboardLogin instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuTableView"];

                                   [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
                                   [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
                                   [self.revealViewController setRearViewController:rearViewController animated:YES];

                                   [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[rootViewController] animated:YES];

                               } else {
                                   //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:SITR_HOME_SEGUE sender:self];
                                   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SitterHomeStoryboard" bundle:nil];
                                   SitterHomeViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SitterHomeViewController"];

                                   UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
                                   [navController setViewControllers: @[rootViewController] animated: YES];

                                   [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
                                   [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
                                   [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[rootViewController] animated:YES];
                               }
```

at the first storyboard here my code to access the rear:

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
if (revealViewController) {
    [self.menuButton setTarget:self.revealViewController];
    [self.menuButton setAction:@selector(revealToggle:)];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}
```

Comment: It seems that i cannot access the "revealViewController" - help please.

Comment: Did you figure out what is the issue?